# iOS Core Animation: Show and hide effect

Tags: ios, animation

I want to create an animation using Core Animation like:

> - Image A is showed from 1s to 3s. After 3s, hide it.
> - Image B is showed from 5s to 7s. After 7s, hide it.

My code:

```
    var animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.duration = 3.0
    // animate from fully visible to invisible
    animation.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 1.0)
    animation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
    animation.beginTime = 2
    animation.removedOnCompletion = true
    layer1.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animateOpacity")

    animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animation.duration = 3.0
    // animate from fully visible to invisible
    animation.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 1.0)
    animation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
    animation.beginTime = 5
    animation.removedOnCompletion = true
    layer2.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animateOpacity")
```

How can I implement it? Thank you :)

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: In the same image view? would you want the image blank when there is nothing to display from 0s to 1s and between 3s and 5s

Comment: @Anbu: I added my code, please refresh to see it :)

Comment: @Oliver: No, I want to display 2 difference images :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can do in varies ways

Check the link...
**http://www.appcoda.com/view-animation-in-swift/**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let firstImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bg01.png"))
    firstImageView.frame = view.frame
    view.addSubview(firstImageView)

    imageFadeIn(firstImageView)

}

func imageFadeIn(imageView: UIImageView) {

    let secondImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bg02.png"))
    secondImageView.frame = view.frame
    secondImageView.alpha = 0.0

    view.insertSubview(secondImageView, aboveSubview: imageView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 2.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        secondImageView.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: {_ in
            imageView.image = secondImageView.image
            secondImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    })

}
```